# Quartz: Single thread some times running twice

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

My application triggers daily three times, some times same scheduler running twice after immediately finishing the job. This behavior is not consistent.

Quartz config details:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=1
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=5
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
```

Triggers:

```
     SCHED_NAME,    TRIGGER_NAME,       TRIGGER_GROUP,      CRON_EXPRESSION,    TIME_ZONE_ID
     ocscheduler     AusNzlJobTrigger    DEFAULT         0 0 17 ? * SUN-THU *    Australia/Melbourne
     ocscheduler     UKJobTrigger        DEFAULT         0 0 22 ? * SUN-THU *   Europe/London
     ocscheduler     AmericaJobTrigger   DEFAULT         0 0 20 ? * SUN-THU * America/New_York
```

If any body encountered  same problem, please help me to resolve this issue.
I am finding difficulty to find the root cause, some times why same job  running twice.

Comment: why do you have 3 triggers ?

Comment: Processing strategy is different for each trigger.

Comment: Hi Madhusudhan Kg, it's been over a month since you posted this question and I answered it. If you found my answer to be of any help, it'd be nice of you to mark it as accepted (the check under the voting arrows). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your job is not allowed to run concurrently (you are using `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` or some other mechanism), and if it takes longer to finish than the interval between scheduled hours (e.g. the New York trigger takes more than 5 hours), a misfire might happen where, depending on your configuration, one of your triggers could fire twice the same day: once for yesterday's misfired execution, and once more for today's scheduled execution.

Bear in mind also that:

> 17:00 in Melbourne's timezone is 07:00 UTC.
>   22:00 in New York's timezone is 02:00 UTC.
>   20:00 in London's timezone is 19:00 UTC.

Anyway, it'd be nice if you included the code for your triggers' scheduling.